# Can I install SP2013 in a domain controller? for DEV

Tags: installation

I am trying to install on AMazon AWS a sharepoint farm for dev purposes which I can shutdown when not needed for saving costs.

I have susccesfully created a VPC and a DC, I also launched a new instance, but I cant join the new server to the domain, it just doensnt work and all this networking stuff its confusing.

I got this resource:
http://sharepoint-tutorial.net/page/install-sharepoint-2013-powershell.aspx

Where they explain that its not recommended, but why? what would fail? what cant work if on the same server as the DC?

I already trying this in the past, and UPS never started but I am not sure if that is the reason or not.

Comment: I've tried this multiple times and something always goes wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Azure Workflow can't be installed on a Domain Controller ([comment of Todd](http://sharepoint-tutorial.net/post/2012/07/16/sharepoint-2013-installation.aspx#comment)), "loose lot of functions (Especially User Profiles and My Sites)" and "lots of unexpected behavior in service application such as User profile, Search". ([Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/syedi/archive/2012/07/26/sharepoint-2013-preview-stand-alone-server-set-up-facts-and-fallacies.aspx))

Check the video how to install it on DC.

http://sharepoint-tutorial.net/post/2012/07/18/install-sharepoint-2013-domain-controller.aspx

Comment: I think you meant workflow manager?

Answer (score 1):

I think dating back to SP 2007 there have been major issues and headaches installing SP on domain controllers.

This article on 2010 issues should give you an idea of the headache it causes:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2637209/en-us